# Azure Alert Condition works in dev but has missing variables for tst

Tags: azure, powershell, powershell-7.2

**Background,**
I am testing deployment of Alerts Rules, Conditions and Action Groups. I have started with 3 alerts.

**Issue,**

- The Alerts rules and conditions are deployed as expected in Dev. When they get deployed to tst, some of the conditions variables are empty/null. This occurs for all 3 alert rules.
- No errors are coming from the pipeline scripts. With most sections of the code having try/catch.

Here is an example:

Here is a dev alert rule and condition
[image: Dev Condition]

Here is the test alert rule and condition
[image: Test Condition]

Here is the core deployment code:

```
Try {
    $dim1 = New-AzMetricAlertRuleV2DimensionSelection -DimensionName $dimentionName -ValuesToInclude $dimentionValue

    $condition = New-AzMetricAlertRuleV2Criteria `
        -MetricName $metricName `
        -MetricNameSpace $metricNameSpace `
        -TimeAggregation $timeAggregation `
        -Operator $operator `
        -Threshold $threshold `
        -DimensionSelection $dim1
}
catch {
    Write-Output "${alertName}: set condition Error"
}

Try {
    Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 `
    -Name $alertName  `
    -resourceGroupName $mgnResourceGroup `
    -WindowSize $aggregationGranularity `
    -Frequency $frequencyofEvaluation `
    -TargetresourceId $targetResourceId `
    -Condition $condition `
    -AutoMitigate $autoMitigate `
    -ActionGroupId $actionGroupId `
    -Description $alertDescription  `
    -Severity $severity `
}
catch
{
    Write-Output "${alertName}: add alert Error"
}
```

**Edit 1** Additional research:

Here is the comparison of the base ARM templates.

Dev.
[image: Dev ARM template]

Test.
[image: Test ARM template]

Thank you for reading.

I appreciate all thoughts and ideas about the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an access issues. I could not see alert information as I did not have permission in test to see the metrics on the target resource.

To fix, add either reader access to the resource group or "monitoring reader" access to the resource group.